# Safest approach when designing storage server

Tags: storage, raid1, raid6, safety

We are planing cloud solution for our customers and we are really concerned with designing safest storage servers for their files.

This storage won't be IO demanding, as it will contain only files which are uploaded by users. Databases will be stored on completely other servers, and are not topic of this discussion.

We are ordering 2 storage servers where one of them will replicate other one.

I'm torn between these two approaches:

1. 12 HDD split in 6 x 2 HDD in Raid 1
2. put all 12 HDD in Raid 6

The other machine would replicate first one, and would have the same choice of disk organising.

I'm not troubled by sharding in case 1., i can easily solve that in my software and i'm not worried by loosing storage space, or storage speed.

Because, we plan to store large amount of data, we have chosen NL-SAS (basically SATA) drives.

If we take safety as main deciding factor, which approach would you choose and why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: If you are after safety from disk failures - use Raid 6. It handles 2 drive failures (complete or bit errors) at the same time. Your solution number 1 is basically a raid 10 which handles most but not all 2-disk-errors and is therefor less safe than Raid 6.

Comment: But, am i wrong to think that if i have second computer doing replication of same data on another two disks which are also in raid 1, basically i would have 3 tolerable drive failures?

Comment: In reality, no. While there's a high chance of one drive in both to fail (so you have two), there's always the chance of a double-drive failure on the *same* server resulting in loss of the array.

Comment: Yep, but with Raid 6 you have still one tolerable failure more (4) and more space net. Besides that consider the amount of time it needs to rebuild a complete array during which you run on reduced redundancy while your remaining disks are under heavy io - mostly restoring data which is not really lost on the failed array...

Comment: @tim when you say that rebuilding array takes time, you are talking about RAID6, right?

Comment: @GoranRadulovic rebuilding an array after a drive failure takes time on any raid level (except RAID 0, which has no provision for such things - you spend your time restoring from backups instead).